# Matplotlib/Python: customize a Zoom-in at show call

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a candlestick chart that is dinamically created for different lengths and stocks. The chart is created first (the creation of the chart is contained in a function "createChart") and not shown until the moment the user presses on the button "Show Chart", that will hence call the instruction .show() and display the plot previously created. When the user clicks on the button he gets the following result:

[image: Original plot]

However, what I would like to get is a chart that is already zoomed-in, let's say, on the last 5% of data. So what I would like to get is when the user presses on the button "Show Chart" the plot (that has been already fully created into the "createChart" function) should zoom on the last couple of months, so Nov 2012 - Dec 2012, but so allowing the user to scroll back/forward:

[image: What I would like to get at show call]

Hence my question is: to make the chart more user-friendly and zoom-in directly on the last observations (that in finance are the most relevant), but still giving the user the possibility of slide the chart and going back or forward as he wishes, how could I customize the .show() method to get this result?

Comment: As I understand, a simple change in axis limits  with `xlim` and `ylim` is not sufficient? You really want to execute the action of zooming?

Comment: What I need is that the chart shows on the last N observations, but all the older observations are into the same chart and it's enough to slide it back to see them. I'm new to Matplotlib: I've understood that xlim and ylim won't lead to this result but will just bound the chart to a certain interval, not allowing the user to slide the same chart back. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `xlim((from, to))` and `ylim((from, to))`?
It limits only the view, not what data is actually plotted. You might have to pay attention to the case where you have a whole lot of data, then the plot() or show() command takes ages to load.

Comment: Oh, so if I want the last 5% of observations to be shown, can I just write something like:
`a = gca()`, then `a.set_xlim([int(len(series)*0.95), int(len(series)]))` and get the right result? I'm trying to implement it but I get "date value out of range" error, maybe I'm coding wrong :/

Comment: Succeeded. Thanks a lot, didn't know that they were just limiting the view. As expected is really slow to slide back-forward (probably for the huge amount of data), do you think there's any way to fix this?

Comment: I usually do something like: `x_tmp = xlim()` (this returns the current axis-limits), then `xlim((x_tmp[1] * 0.95, x_tmp[1]))`.

Answer (score 4):

I propose you to use the navigation toolbar tools; here is an example:

```
from pylab import *
x=[1,2,2,3,5]
y=[2,3,4,5,6]
fig=figure() # create and store a figure
tb=fig.canvas.toolbar # get the toolbar of the figure
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) # add axes to the figure
ax.plot(x,y) # plot
tb.push_current() # save the current zoom in the view stack
ax.set_xlim([1,3]) # change xlims
ax.set_ylim([2,5]) # change ylims
tb.push_current() # save the new position in the view stack
show() # show the figure
```

Comment: Solved already, I will try to implement this at a second stage when I will be into the optimization phase. Thanks!

Comment: The goal here is to enable you going back to the whole view with the navigation buttons (home or back). If you only do `xlim` and `ylim` your user with have to unzoom at hand in order to see the whole plot.